# Java: Objects relations with criteria (hibernate)

Tags: java, hibernate, criteria

I have a problem with criteria and relation between objects.
I present a simple scheme before:

I have 2 objects:

A is the parent
B is the child with a link at parent.

I know how to create a query to have B with A's restriction:

```
Criteria criteria = this.getSession().createCriteria(B.class);
criteria.add(Property.forName("a.name").eq("test"));
```

But my problem is the next:

How to retrieve all A objects with a B's restricition without direct link between A at B ?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't have a direct link between A and B in your object graph, the only way to do what you want will be to create a custom SQL query (or HQL) in your criteria.

Similar to

```
criteria.add ( Restrictions.sqlRestriction("b.parent_id = a.id"))
```

Check the [documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/querycriteria.html) on criteria for more information.

Comment: PS - I just jotted that code down without trying it, I'm not sure if it works right as is -- but you can in fact add sql restrictions as demonstrated.

Answer (score -1):

just check the posts here it's useful and I tried it and it worked
https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?t=943792